# PHP do-while loop ending with exhausted memory error when executing sql code

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Whilst executing the following code, the site crashes with:

"Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 254643 bytes)"

```
        $queID = "LCGQ00" . $ID;
        $sqlquecheck = "Select QueryID FROM Questions Where QueryID = '$queID' limit 1;";
        $quequery = $this->db->query($sqlquecheck);

        if($quequery->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            do{
                $queID = $queID . "-" . $ID;
                $quequery = $this->db->query($sqlquecheck);
            }while($quequery->num_rows() > 0);
        }
```

The error is pointing to the following line of code as the culprit:

```
$queID = $queID . "-" . $ID;
```

What I'm trying to do is pad an existing ID to create a new one, and if that already exist then pad it again and again and so on.

So if there is already a result, do the pad function then resend the query and check again if it still returns a result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit FIXED:

```
        if($quequery->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            do{
                $queID = $queID . "-" . $ID;
                $sqlquecheck2 = "Select QueryID FROM Questions Where QueryID = '$queID' limit 1;";
                $quequery2 = $this->db->query($sqlquecheck2);
            }while($quequery2->num_rows() > 0);
        }
```

Also fetch_* and other methods were not working when I tried a different approach, which is why I used this method. This didn't need to be perfect, was just to eliminate a db error. Thanks again.

Comment: doesn't `$quequery->num_rows()` never decrease?

Comment: also, reusing variables is propbably not the best idea here

Comment: I assumed that when I rerun 

    $quequery = $this->db->query($sqlquecheck);

if there was no result for the new ID it would return 0?

Comment: Yes, you rerun it, but it only executes a select. you are not changing anything about the database's contents, so your query will return the same result every single time.

Comment: If you're limiting to 1 and doing a match query, why not just use fetch_row?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs you have a point, but it would be far more efficient to load all the duplicates and loop over them once

Comment: @TimothyGroote ah didn't know that :) then I'd recommend a straight up while loop on fetch assoc

Comment: @LukeHipkiss in order to solve the actual problem you are having (yes, it's an X Y problem) http://xyproblem.info/ , is there any simple way of keeping the records apart after you have retreived them from the database? just fetching the duplicates isn't going to solve it, you will need to update the records in the database.

Comment: If we're re-engineering it,  I'd just add an integer 'version' column, and increment that each time you re-use the QueryID.  Much more efficient then to get the next number with e.g. (Select max(version)+1 where QueryID='foo')

Comment: @jeffUK that would be one way, but i'm beginning to fear op's table has no unique identifier to begin with, and he's trying to solve that... :(

Comment: I thought because I was changing the `$queID` used in the WHERE of the Select, the answer would change, but it seems it wasn't, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're never changing `$sqlquecheck`, so it will run while  `Select QueryID FROM Questions Where QueryID = 'LCGQ00' limit 1;"` returns something.

Unless some other process changes the database, it will run either 0 times or forever.

try

```
$queID = "LCGQ00" . $ID;
        $sqlquecheck = "Select QueryID FROM Questions Where QueryID = '$queID' limit 1;";
        $quequery = $this->db->query($sqlquecheck);

        if($quequery->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            do{
                $queID = $queID . "-" . $ID;
                $sqlquecheck = "Select QueryID FROM Questions Where QueryID = '$queID' limit 1;";

                $quequery = $this->db->query($sqlquecheck);
            }while($quequery->num_rows() > 0);
        }
```

Comment: Oh, So I recreated the `$sqlquecheck` and `$quequery` inside the do-while, works perfectly now, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Although it does seem you're going about things in a slightly unusual way;  consider using e.g. an auto-incrementing integer field to generate your unique ID, there are lots of downsides to the way you're doing it.  Not least in ending up with IDs that are hundreds of characters long!